# Buscar una pagina en el proyecto con VScode

Tags: vscode

Estoy usando VScode para programar en php y en ocasiones quiero buscar una pagina por su nombre dentro del proyecto (ejemplo: eliminarcoche.php que esta en una subcarpeta), con ctrt + t  el vscode me abre un campo de búsqueda pero por lo que veo me busca solo funciones y clases dentro del proyecto, ¿hay alguna manera de buscar dentro de mi proyecto el nombre de un archivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El comando para buscar un archivo en `VSCode` es <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, de igual forma te abrirá un buscador con todos los archivos disponibles, además te permite buscar por extensión del archivo escribiendo por ejemplo: `.css`.

Para futuras consulta te recomendaría este documento oficial con todos los atajos de `VSCode`:

> https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf